# MVC Textbox with float number using comma: from razor view to the controller . [Globalization?]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, textbox, globalization

I'm using MVC3 + Razor.

I'm sending a parameter on a textbox to a Controller. 
I'm using the "es-AR" globalization.
I want a float number to have this format:  "9,99" (comma as a decimal separator)

When I put a "comma separator" number in the textbox, the controller receives NULL on the "weight"variable. When I put a "dot separator", the weight float variable is OK.

View:

```
@Html.TextBox("weight")
```

(Basically, this is a search field. )

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult UserQueryPage(float? weight )
```

web.config:

```
  <system.web>
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-AR" />
```

Is there anything else that I can do about it? 
Any tip?

Thanks!

Comment: `<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-AR" />` should work. I am unable to reproduce the issue. Could you please post a full example including your controller and view allowing to illustrate the problem? By the way are you using AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

The Default Model Binder doesn't take locale into account so the value with the comma will never bind correctly! You'll need a custom Model Binder for decimals
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx

Comment: This seems to be the solution, I'll be testing it and getting back to you. Thanks!